# Output form within html page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to print the submitted input elements within the same page below the html form. The checked checkbox  elements should all be printed. The image element can be avoided.

The function does not seem to be working.

```js
function validateForm(myForm) {
  var a = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = y;
  var b = document.getElementByName("passwords").value;
  document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = y;
  var c = document.getElementByName("gender");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
    if (c[i].checked)
      document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = c[i].value; //looping through radio buttons

  }
  var d = document.getElementByName("hobbies");
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
    if (d[i] checked)
      ans = ans + d[i].value; //looping through checkboxes and adding to display in display 2 id.

  }
  document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = ans;
  var e = document.getElementByName("cities").value;
  document.getElementById("display3").innerHTML = e;

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="fname" <br>Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwords" />
    <br>Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female</input>
    <br>Hobbies:
    <input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="Reading" />Reading
    <input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="Writing" />Writing</input>
    <br>City:
    <select name="cities" />
    <option>Surat</option>
    <option>Ahmedabad</option>
    <option>Rajkot</option>
    <option>Vadodra</option>
    </select>
    <br>Image:
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" value="image" style="margin:0px 10px 10px 100px; margin:absolute;" />
</form>
<br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" onSubmit="validateform(myForm);">

</fieldset>

<p id="display"></p>//display the values submitted within the html page
<p id="display1"></p>
<p id="display2"></p>
<p id="display3"></p>
```

Comment: Should it be `getElementsByName`?

Answer (score 1):

1. getElementsByName - plural and when accessing the first, use [0] like 
   `document.getElementsByName("cities")[0].value`
2. missing a dot in `d[i].checked`
3. move the `onSubmit="validateform(myForm);"` to the form tag and do `onSubmit="return validateForm(this);"` and add return false;
4. validateForm misspelled in event handler (lower case f)
5. y missing
6. ans not defined

```js
function validateForm(myForm) {
  var a = document.getElementById("fname").value;
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = a;
  var b = document.getElementsByName("passwords").value;
  document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = a;
  var c = document.getElementsByName("gender");
  var i, ans;
  for (i = 0; i < c.length; ++i) {
    if (c[i].checked)
      document.getElementById("display1").innerHTML = c[i].value; //looping through radio buttons

  }
  var d = document.getElementsByName("hobbies");
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
    if (d[i].checked)
      ans = ans + d[i].value; //looping through checkboxes and adding to display in display 2 id.

  }
  document.getElementById("display2").innerHTML = ans;
  var e = document.getElementsByName("cities")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("display3").innerHTML = e;
  return false; // normally when error but here to stay on page

}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" onSubmit="return validateForm(this);">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Details</legend>
    Name:
    <input type="text" id="fname" <br>Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" id="passwords" />
    <br>Gender:
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" />Female</input>
    <br>Hobbies:
    <input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="Reading" />Reading
    <input type="radio" name="hobbies" value="Writing" />Writing</input>
    <br>City:
    <select name="cities" />
    <option>Surat</option>
    <option>Ahmedabad</option>
    <option>Rajkot</option>
    <option>Vadodra</option>
    </select>
    <br>Image:
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" value="image" style="margin:0px 10px 10px 100px; margin:absolute;" />
</form>
<br>
<input type="Submit" value="Submit">

</fieldset>

<p id="display"></p><!-- display the values submitted within the html page -->
<p id="display1"></p>
<p id="display2"></p>
<p id="display3"></p>
```

Comment: also `//` is javascript comment if you want to comment out html use `<!-- comment -->`

Comment: Yeah, but I assumed that was for the question